# How do I change default session on Ubuntu 11.04 Live CD

Tags: 11.04, unity, live-cd, session, gnome-classic

I'm working on a remaster of an Ubuntu 11.04 live CD and I would like the default session to be Ubuntu Classic instead of Unity when booting into the live environment. What file(s) do I need to modify to achieve this? Ubuntu forums, google, and man pages are not helping me turn up the information I need.

Comment: Uninstall Unity, Ubuntu will default to the Classic Session.

Answer (score 1):

OP accepted this comment as an answer:

> Uninstall Unity, Ubuntu will default to the Classic Session